# cvCreateFileCapture always returns "NULL"

Tags: ios, opencv, ffmpeg

I am making an iphone-app with Xcode 4.3.3 and OpenCV 2.4

I used that "cvCreateFileCapture("simtom.mp4")" to get frame from '.mp4' file but unfortunately, cvCreateFileCapture() always returns "NULL".

What is the problem?

Here is my source code.

```
 CvCapture *m_pMusicVideo;     

 m_pMusicVideo = cvCreateFileCapture("simtom.mp4");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the simtom.mp4 file is in the same folder as your executable file. If you have it in the same folder as your source file it won't be found. In Xcode 4, this means the derived data folder. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations to see where that is.

**Edit**

I didn't realize you were trying to run under iOS. (I added that tag to your question.) Your problem, then, is that the simtom.mp4 file isn't being copied to the iPhone along with the app. In order for that to happen you need to embed simtom.mp4 into your application bundle and open it from there. You should be able to get the path to the file with

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"simtom.mp4"];
```

You include the file in your bundle in the target's Build Phases:

[image: Build Phase]

Here is the developer documentation [on NSBundle resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html). The general [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html) is also a good read.

Comment: I moved to "simtom.mp4" in the path "/Users/1w1w/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARDemo-hiarxwwvdhkhsceukxohkbyxxguy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/"
however cvCreateFileCapture() still returns NULL.
how do I solve this cvCreateFileCapture() problem?

Comment: oh. I saw your edited answer. so I know my "simtom.mp4" was not in "Bundle Resources". then I added my "simtom.mp4" in "Bundle Resources". so I correctly checked my "simtom.mp4" is "Bundle Resources". however my cvCreateFileCapture() still returns NULL.
I definitely added "simtom.mp4" in my "Bundle resource".
so I guess opencv 2.4 maybe has some problem to handle '.mp4' file.
do you know contents about cvCreateFileCapture() in opencv 2.4?

Comment: You can't open it with `cvCreateFileCapture("simtom.mp4");` The .mp4 file isn't in the same folder as the executable in the bundle. You need to prepend the file path. That's what `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"simtom.mp4"];` is for.